Recursive type not working with optional properties
I have a type definition that allows me to navigate through an object via an array of strings / indices representing the keys of the object or nested arrays:
export type PredicateFunction<ArrayType> = (array: ArrayType, index?: number) => boolean;
export type IndexOrPredicateFunction<Type> = number | PredicateFunction<Type>;
export type StatePathKey = IndexOrPredicateFunction<any> | string;

export type StatePath<Obj, Path extends (string | IndexOrPredicateFunction<any>)[] = []> =
    object extends Obj
        ? Path
        : Obj extends object
            ? (Path |
                    // Check if object is array
                    (Obj extends readonly any[] ?
                        // ...when array only allow index or PredicateFunction
                        StatePath<Obj[number], [...Path, IndexOrPredicateFunction<Obj[number]>]>
                        // ...when object generate type of all possible keys
                        : { [Key in string & keyof Obj]: StatePath<Object[Key], [...Path, Key]> }[string & keyof Obj]))
            : Path;

This works for e.g. this interface:
interface State1  {
    test: {
        nestedTest: boolean
    }
}

like this:
const t1: StatePath<State1> = ['test', 'nestedTest']; 

But it breaks as soon as I have an optional property:
interface State2  {
    test: {
        nestedTest?: boolean
    }
}

Any idea how to solve this? I already tried to use the -? on the type without success.
Find a sandbox for reproduction here: Typescript playground

(Please note that Object is a type that already exists and it's distracting at best to shadow it with a type param name. Pls change to Obj or something else.) I wonder what you want to see with unions. I'd say for this particular example if you've got weak object types (all optional properties) then object extends Obj isn't going to do what you want and you'd need object extends Required<Obj> or some other check for wide types. See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yes that was exactly what i was looking for - thank you!

The simplest fix for this particular issue would be to change your check from object extends Obj to object extends Required<Obj>. If Obj turns out to be a weak type, meaning it's an object type where all the properties are optional, then TypeScript will see the empty object type {} and the object type as assignable to it.  So, for example, object extends {a?: string, b?: number} is true. But then the type will bail out where you don't want it to.
There are various ways to proceed, but by using the Required<T> utility type you'd compare object to a version of the type where the optional properties are made required. And while object extends {a?: string, b?: number} is true, object extends Required<{a?: string, b?: number}> (a.k.a. object extends {a: string, b: number}) is false.  And so now the type won't bail out unless Obj really is empty, or object, or unknown, etc.
Playground link to code

Perfect, thanks!
